# Problem renaming xcode classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i'm trying to rename my classes in iOS project in xcode but i cant.

If i try to rename the file in navigator, or if i make refactor -> rename on class name in .h file, it replace all except .h and .m file, it say me:

"Unable to rename oldName to newName, oldName couldn't be moved to appName"

How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Same Problem here, would like to know whether you found an answer! It only happens for one file, that really is no different to the others.

Comment: Fixed this, appearently, I can't just rename something when I only change Upper/Lowercase letters while leaving the characters the same.

Answer (score 1):

Type in the name of your project in the finder, and locate the class files and header files inside that. Try renaming it through that